# Javascript only validates the first input field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I've been trying to validate this form using Javascript, however for some weird reason only the first input field seems to be doing what it is supposed to do. Here's the relevant snippet of code:

> ```
> <form method="post" name="myform" action="www.google.com" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
>           <h3 id="secondarytext"><strong>Your details:</strong></h3>
>
>           <div class="label1">    
>               <label for="firstName">First Name</label> 
>                   <input type="text" id="name" name="name"  onblur="validateName(name)" />
>               <span id="nameError" style="display: none;">Please enter your name, you can only use alphabetic characters</span>
>
>               <label for="ssurname" >Surname</label>
>                   <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" onblur="validateSurname(surname)" /> <br />  
>           </div>
> <input type="reset" value="Reset Form">
> <input type="submit" value="Submit">
> </form>
> ```

Javascript:

```
function validateName(x) 
    {
      var re = /^[A-Za-z]{2,25}$/; 


      if(re.test(document.getElementById(x).value)){  /* This checks the input's value corresponds with the regular expression (re) */
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#ccffcc'; /* If it does it changes the background colour of the field to green*/
        document.getElementById(x).style.border="4px solid #ccffcc";
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none"; /* This hides the error message because the function returned as true */
        return true;
      }
      else{ /* If the function doesn't return as true this is what happens */
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#e35152'; /* The background colour of the field changes to red */
        document.getElementById(x).style.border="4px solid #e35152";
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block"; /* This displays the error message */
        return false; 
      }
    }

function validateSurname(x) 
    {
      var re = /^[A-Za-z]{2,25}$/; 


      if(re.test(document.getElementById(x).value)){ 
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#ccffcc'; 
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none"; 
        return true;
        }
      else{ 
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#e35152'; 
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block"; 
        return false; 
        }
    }


function validateForm()
{
    var error = 0;
    if(!validateName('name')) 
     {
       document.getElementById('nameError').style.display = "block"; 
       error++;
     }

     if(!validateSurname('surname')) 
     {
       document.getElementById('surnameError').style.display = "block"; 
       error++;
     }

    if(error > 0) 
      {
        return false;
      }
      else if(error < 0) { 
        return true;
      }
}
```

Comment: You don't have an element with id `surnameError`.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but you have "ssurname" in the `<label>` element.

Comment: The JavaScript console in Firefox/Firebug or Chrome' developer tools is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe these changes will help you:

1) Add the error message you want to show when surname is wrong:

```
<label for="ssurname" >Surname</label>
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" onblur="validateSurname('surname')" /> <br />  
<span id="surnameError" style="display: none;">Please enter your surname, you can only use alphabetic characters</span>
```

2) Pass a string to the parameter instead of a javascript var (e.g. do `validateSurname('surname')` instead of `validateSurname(surname)`), as the function you've defined is expecting a string as a parameter.

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uzyLogc1/1/

Comment: Makes sense! Should have took a moment to look though my HTML properly rather than blaming the Javascript. Thanks for your help buddy!